# PowerShell command fails if put into cmd file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to put the following PowerShell command in a cmd file to execute (it works beautifully when called from the PS command line):

```
dir stand/*.jpg | %{$x=0} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName "Base$x.jpg"; $x++ }
```

I get the following error:

> '{$x' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I tried to put double `$$` instead of single `$`, and double `%%` instead of single `%`, but it still fails.

Am I missing some kind of escaping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use PowerShell commands inside a `*.cmd` file, not directly...

Put the command inside a `*.ps1` file and call it with powershell, e.g.

```
powershell -file "c:\users\me\myscript.ps1"
```

Of course you can call powershell directly from your cmd file and pass the command as an argument, but this is always tricky, because you have to escape stuff etc. Sometimes you can get around it easily by using single quotes inside your command:

```
powershell -Command "$x=0; dir stand/*.jpg | foreach {Rename-Item $_.FullName ('Base' + $x++ + '.jpg')}"
```